# ListBox and selectedIndexChanged event after the user hit the back button

Tags: windows-phone-7

In my windows phone 7 app, I have the following code to handle the OnSelectedIndexChange of a ListBox.

```
 private void wordList_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            WordList selectedList = (WordList)e.AddedItems[0];
            NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Views/Game.xaml?ListName=" + selectedList.Name, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
        }
```

The above code work fine, However if the user click on the hardware back button from the Game page,  and click on the same listbox item, the above code is not called.  I assume this is because the selected item is the same therefore the SelectionChanged event is not being called.

How do I make it so that if the user select the same item I can still send them to the Game page?

I looked at the Tap Event but I couldn't figure out a way to get the selected Item from the tab event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This way you can get the selected Item from the Tap event.

```
private void wordList_Tap(object sender, GestureEventArgs e)
{
    var selectedElement = e.OriginalSource as FrameworkElement;
    if (selectedElement != null)
    {
        var selectedData = selectedElement.DataContext as WordList;
        if (selectedData != null)
        {
            NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Views/Game.xaml?ListName=" + selectedData.Name, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When using SelectionChanged to navigate, surround your navigation logic with a check to see if the SelectedIndex = -1. After you navigate, set the index to -1, so that the event will not fire twice.

```
   private void wordList_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
            {
               var lb = sender as ListBox;
                if (lb != null)
                  {
                      if (lb.SelectedIndex == -1) return;

                WordList selectedList = (WordList)e.AddedItems[0];
                NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Views/Game.xaml?ListName=" + selectedList.Name, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
                     lb.SelectedIndex = -1;
               }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had such issue within a UserControl. Check the sender, and return if it is not the ListBox control which is triggering the event:

```
  protected void cbEvents_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    if (sender is DropDownList)
      RebindGrid();
  }
```